# The mini border adjustment Dot Game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to develop a mini game where you click the Dot and the Position will be randomly generated and the size of the Dot will shrink the more you click it. The border can also be scalable depending from its device.

Any suggestion/Ideas in how can I scale the Dot within the borders without going over the line?

Here is my simple code:

```css
.Box{  
 position: relative; 
 box-sizing: border-box;  
 border: 1px solid black ;
 height: 700px;
 width: auto; 
 margin: 2%;
 padding: 0px; 
}


.Dot{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 96%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="Box">
             <div class="Dot"></div>
            </div>
            
        
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dot is 50px tall and wide you can put a padding of half of the size around the main box, in this case it'll be 25px of padding.

Then you can add another div inside the box which will be 100% of the box's height and width, set it's position as a relative and have the dot move inside the inner container.

As long you keep consistently the size of the dot and padding of the box half of the dot size the dot will never overflow outside its parent containers.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 700px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 2%;
  padding: 25px;
}

.Inner{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Dot{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 96%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<div class="Box">
  <div class="Inner">
    <div class="Dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is going to work. If you dont mind that I ask. What are the 
`*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`
for?

Comment: `*` means wildcard, when you write css rules inside that block they will be applied to all the elements in the html. So the above will apply `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements and their `before`/`after` pseudo-elements